# I don't get this cartoon! Pem"broke"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, jokes

This question wants you to choose the correct aspect based on the (supposedly funny) cartoon.
Oddly enough, I don't have a problem answering it, I just don't understand what it's asking!

[image]

Where is the joke?

Comment: I think you are trying to read far too much into the character's name. Its just a name.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 But that's the only thing that relates the caption to the cartoon, isn't it?

Comment: I think the joke is visual not verbal.

Comment: The joke is that he's been thinking too hard and broke his head/his brain exploded/etc.

Comment: By the way, if the cartoon really had been published with the two choices in the text I might find it funnier than it originally was: With the text as given the person on the left seems to *avoid* making a decision about the correct tense to use in a question about the other person's decision-making. - Then again, still not very funny.

Comment: It seems this cartoon is taken from a textbook where a cartoon has been repurposed to ask the reader to choose the correct option. The original cartoon would probably have been in a newspaper, with a different caption.

Answer (score 33):

There's a common wisecrack I've heard, and it goes something like this:

> **Person A**: I've been thinking...
>   **Person B**: Oh, so that's why I smell smoke.

Jokes like these are intended to compare the brain to some sort of mechanical device. *Think too hard* (the reasoning goes) *and you might experience some sort of mechanical failure.*

This cartoon plays off that line of logic. Apparently, Pembroke (and, as the commenters have said, that's just a name – it might as well be "Jones") has a reputation for being indecisive, to the point where his head "explodes" when he needs to make a decision. In this case, a co-worker is making a casual observation of the aftermath.

I understand the comic, but I don't find it hilariously funny. It's mildly amusing at best, and could be labeled as [*dry humor*](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dry-joke.590320/).

Answer (score 3):

I checked out the word **Pembroke** in Wikipedia and found this:

The town and county derive their names from the cantref of Penfro: Pen = "head" or "end", and bro = "region", "country", "land", which has been interpreted to mean either "Land's End" or "headland"

Comment: Welcome to ELL! While this is useful information to have, it doesn't seem to shed much light on the reason this cartoon is funny, since "land's end"/"headland" don't have any particular humorous associations with the picture or caption.

Comment: I agree that it's useful information, and so should be flagged as "not an answer" so a moderator can migrate it to a comment.

Comment: On closer examination, the OP appears to imply, in the question's title, a question about the name so it's perhaps responsive but arguably not complete.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. "head", "end" and "broke" connect the name and the situation together. Maybe that's why the character is named what it is.

Comment: @cst1992 - I'm inclined to agree with you. The character's name is not the main point of the joke; however, either the cartoonist managed to embed a layer of subtlety into the comic, or else the name's origin is one helluva coincidence. In any case, it's good research by Steven Gregory.

Comment: No matter how good the research, this is still _not an answer_. I've flagged it as such. It'd make a fine comment.

Comment: While the observations about the etymology of "Pembroke" are interesting, I can't believe that the cartoonist intended something so incredibly subtle. If the humour depends in any significant way on an understanding of Welsh toponymy then... let's just say that it's a joke that very few people are going to understand.

Answer (score -1):

`Pembroke` is just a name, it has no other significance.

Any humour in the cartoon will come from knowledge of the character over time in a regular comic strip.  I can't speak for others but the frame presented contains no comedic elements.

It's likely from their clothing that Pembroke is some middle-manager who has no real decision-making power but will bear the responsibility for making their bosses' poorly thought out schemes work, but that's entirely a guess.

Comment: Kreiri's comment, above, is the correct explanation of the joke (with the correct answer being "been trying").

Comment: @user5505 - above where... I'm still not sure that's what the intent of the cartoon was, if a characters head has exploded it wasn't drawn well, it just looks like poorly drawn hair and certainly wasn't obvious.  Either option would be acceptable since both convey that an attempt to perform some action was made.